# Crystal report: how to create text object in crystal report during runtime im using vb.net/VS2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, runtime, crystal-reports-2010, dynamic-controls

i want to create a dynamic text object in crystal report during runtime. i want to make it as a column or display horizontally (sample1. date range from 7/1/2013 - 7/31/2013 ) in crystal report the values is came from the rows count of a dataset and the result of that rows.count is the number of text object that will create in crystal report.

SAMPLE 1:

TASKS CODE | 7/1/2013 | 7/2/2013 | 7/3/2013 | 7/4/2013 | ... | 7/31/2013 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need Dynamic Columns generated at run time

you can have idea about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20670/Dynamic-Crystal-Report-with-C)!

or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98727/Crystal-Reports-with-Dynamic-Number-of-Columns-wit)!